# Nginx proxy_pass to Angular application

Tags: angular, nginx, proxy, request-headers

I'm trying to add headers to all the requests coming out of my Angular application to an external API. In the past, I've done this with by using `proxy_set_header` and pointing `proxy_pass` to the running application.

My configuration is below. As you can see my Angular app is a static file.

```
location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != https) {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to `proxy_pass` to a static application?